# Simple MVC Ajax Troubleshooting

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

trying to learn mvc by making a simple social network and im trying to get ajax to work but instead of updating the target div, the partial view is being returned as a whole new page. Can anyone explain why please?

(there is no difference between post and status in the code below, the naming difference is from because i have tried to copy a tutorial on youtube exactly)

INDEX

```
@Html.Partial("_AddPost", new S1.Models.Post())

<div id="newStatus">
</div>
```

ADD POST PARTIAL

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePost", "Wall", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "newStatus"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Post</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">

        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Username, new { Value = User.Identity.Name })

        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostContent)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostContent)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostContent)
        </div>

        @{
    TempData["returnURL"] = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="postStatus" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

CREATE POST ACTION

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public PartialViewResult CreatePost(Post Post)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string wallID = TempData["wallID"].ToString();

                Post.PostDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
                Post.Wallname = wallID;

                db.Posts.Add(Post);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return PartialView("_NewStatusPartial",Post);


            }

            return PartialView("All",Post);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use this Html Helper -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePost", "Wall", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "newStatus"}))
{
```

With the AjaxOptions overload that you are passing.  You need to switch to using Ajax.BeginForm()

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreatePost", "Wall", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "newStatus"}))
{
```

Also, be sure that you are including the proper Microsoft.Ajax javascript files in your project and your HTML markup (probably in your layout file).

Going forward, using jQuery to handle form submissions and partial page updates will give you more flexibility in how you code and design your site, but since you are following a tutorial, I do not want to deviate away from your question by throwing those concepts at you.